# How to sort a list correctly in Angular?

Tags: angular, sorting, ionic-framework

I have the following simple sorting algorithm:
In my HTML file I get the column names of my table from a JSON, which I want to sort upwards and downwards. With the method sortData the sorting should be executed depending on the selected column. However, the list is not sorted.

```
<ion-row>
          <ion-col style="width: 5em;" *ngFor="let column of columnsHeader.controls " (click)="sortData(column.name)">
            <div class="table__header" id="hoverId">{{column.name}}</div>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col style="width: 3em;">
            <div class="table__header"></div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
```

My sort algorhythm in the page.ts

```
sortData(value: any){
    console.log(value);
    if (this.sortColumn) {
      const newarr = this.tableInformation.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
      this.tableInformation = newarr;
    }
    else {
      const newarr = this.tableInformation.sort((a, b)=> b.value - a.value);
      this.tableInformation= newarr;
    }
    this.sortColumn=!this.sortColumn;
    console.log(this.sortColumn);

    console.log(this.tableInformation);
  }
```

console.log(value) gives me the desired column name correctly. However, my list cannot be sorted by value. However, if I hardcode my sorting algorithm and enter for example the id or other column name then my list will be sorted by the hardcoded names. Unless the column has string values then unfortunately it doesn't work either.

```
sortData(value: any){
    console.log(value);
    if (this.sortColumn) {
      const newarr = this.tableInformation.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      this.tableInformation = newarr;
    }
    else {
      const newarr = this.tableInformation.sort((a, b)=> b.id - a.id);
      this.tableInformation= newarr;
    }
    this.sortColumn=!this.sortColumn;
    console.log(this.sortColumn);

    console.log(this.tableInformation);
  }
```

Now for my questions:

1. how do I make it so that I can sort my list correctly using value?
2. I would like to have arrows for the sorting in header for the desired columns that signal what is sorted. How can I add the arrows to my list header?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Answer (score 0):

`a.value - b.value` looks for the property `value` on a and b, which is likely undefined

You're probably wanting to use `a[value] - b[value]`

For the arrows you can use
`<ion-icon name="arrow-down-outline"></ion-icon>`
With logic like
`<ion-icon *ngIf="sortingAscended(colname)" name="arrow-up-outline"></ion-icon>`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After adding a[value] - b[value] and b[value] - a[value] respectively, I can at least sort by all columns that have numbers in their fields. But can you explain me why it doesn't work for strings? I read that the sort() method converts all elements to strings and then compares them using UTF-16.